# Get rows without an 'end' event

Tags: t-sql

I have a series of rows representing either start (`S`) or and (`E`) is a `thing`

```
+----+-------+-------+
| Id | Event | Thing |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | S     | A     |
|  2 | E     | A     |
|  3 | S     | B     |
|  4 | E     | B     |
|  5 | S     | C     |
|  6 | S     | D     |
|  7 | S     | E     |
+----+-------+-------+
```

I'm trying to get the rows that have no end event.

```sql
SELECT [a].[Id] AS [ID a],
       [a].[Event] AS [Event a],
       [b].[Id] AS [ID b],
       [b].[Event] AS [Event b]
  FROM [dbo].[TimeSeries] AS [a]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[TimeSeries] AS [b]
    ON [b].[Thing] = [a].[Thing]
   WHERE [a].[Event] = 'S'
   AND [b].[Event] = 'E'
```

This returns

```
+------+---------+------+---------+
| ID a | Event a | ID b | Event b |
+------+---------+------+---------+
|    1 | S       |    2 | E       |
|    3 | S       |    4 | E       |
+------+---------+------+---------+
```

This is where I'm getting stuck.

I want all the IDs that are neither in the `ID a` column nor the `ID b` column.  Then I'm guessing `LEFT JOIN` to find all the rows that have no end event.

> NB: The *real* table is an SSIS log with many millions of rows.

Comment: Please add your sql-server version

Comment: The WHERE-condition changes the Outer Join to Inner. When you move `AND [b].[Event] = 'E'` from WHERE to ON you can simply add `AND [b].[Event] IS NULL` to get your result. But Martin Smith's NOT EXISTS is probably performing better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few ways.

1. Use `NOT EXISTS` [for an anti semi join](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join)

> ```
> SELECT Id,
>        Event,
>        Thing
> FROM   dbo.TimeSeries t1
> WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT *
>                   FROM   dbo.TimeSeries t2
>                   WHERE  t1.Thing = t2.Thing
>                          AND t2.Event = 'E');
> ```

2. Partition by *Thing* and find the minimum (alphabetically first) event in each partition. If it is `S` rather than `E` this *Thing* has no end event.

> ```
> WITH T
>      AS (SELECT *,
>                 MIN(Event) OVER (PARTITION BY Thing) AS Evt
>          FROM   dbo.TimeSeries
>          WHERE  Event IN ( 'E', 'S' ))
> SELECT Id,
>        Event,
>        Thing
> FROM   T
> WHERE  Evt = 'S';
> ```

3. Partition by *Thing* and use `LAG` to look at the preceding row to the current row when ordering by event alphabetically.  If the current row is `S` and there is no preceding row `Evt` will be `NULL`. Just preserve any such rows. This is 2012+ syntax.

> ```
> WITH T
>      AS (SELECT *,
>                 LAG(Event) OVER (PARTITION BY Thing ORDER BY Event) AS Evt
>          FROM   dbo.TimeSeries
>          WHERE  Event IN ( 'E', 'S' ))
> SELECT Id,
>        Event,
>        Thing
> FROM   T
> WHERE  Event = 'S' AND Evt IS NULL;
> ```

Comment: I think the original poster would be helped a lot if you would provide some extra explanation about why your queries give the intended result... specially if s/he doesn't know how to deal with CTE (WITH) and WINDOWS (OVER).

Comment: Cheers, that seems to work perfectly.  What's `LAG`?

Comment: Just found it, extra kudos for using the latest syntax!